# How get the sum for every distinct value in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose my table contains the following:

```
ID    price    
-------------
 1     10      
 1     10      
 2     20      
 2     20      
 3     30
 3     30
```

Each time through a while loop. I want to get the sum of the values on price but only once for every distinct value in ID

So given the example above, I would arrive with something like:

```
ID    price    
-------------
 1     20          
 2     40           
 3     60
```

Just to add, I may have stumble upon a post with a similar inquiry. Problem is that other post uses Oracle, I on the other hand am using MySQL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need [`GROUP BY` and `SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
SELECT ID, 
       SUM(price) AS price
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score -1):

As I reviewed your question, I summarized it by one simple answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ID), SUM(PRICE) 
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Apart from adding an unneeded `DISTINCT` and parentheses that imply you don't understand that  `DISTINCT` operates on the row not individual columns this adds nothing to the answer given 12 years previous