# MySQL - sum values to unique ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with file information, and I query -- SELECT DISTINCT File, Numbers FROM Table -- the table to create a two column table with the name of the file and some numbers i.e.

```
    File |  Numbers
    ---------------
    A    |    1
    A    |    2
    A    |    4
    B    |    3
    B    |    1
    B    |    2
    C    |    5
    C    |    3
    C    |    1
```

I am trying get this result, to sum up this query with the unique file name i.e.

```
    File |  Numbers
    ---------------
    A    |    7
    B    |    6
    C    |    9
```

I can get the individual sum according to the file name via SELECT File, SUM(Numbers) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT File, Numbers FROM Table) WHERE File = 'A'

but I want to have all three present in my results. I have tried - SELECT File, SUM(Numbers) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT File, Numbers FROM Table) but get the result of

```
    File |  Numbers
    ---------------
    C    |    22
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464669/how-get-the-sum-for-every-distinct-value-in-another-column

Answer (score 3):

You need a `group by`:

```
select `File`, sum(`Numbers`) from `tbl` group  by `File`
```