# Sum specific keys in SQL query - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query that returns all fields in a table:

```
$registro = mysqli_query($con, 
  "SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY procedimento LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes");
```

My question is, if possible, through this query, sum the particular column values associated with another column of values, eg

Among other columns there are "Column: Name" where the values are names and "Column: Value" where the values are numbers. The idea is to add up the values associated with the names.

I suppose I do a foreach inside the while, but I have difficulty in this approach.

The following piece code in question:

```
<?php
//...
$registro = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY procedimento     LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes");
$tabela = $tabela.'<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-  hover">
                    <tr>
                  <th width="300">Nome</th>
                  <th width="200">Procedimentos</th>
                  <th width="150">Valor Cobrado do serviço</th>
                  <th width="150">Valor Total dos serviços</th>
                  <th width="150">Porcentagem do Valor Total dos serviços</th>
                  <th width="150">Data</th>
                    </tr>';


while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)){
$porcentagem = ($linha['valor'] * 30) / 100;
$tabela = $tabela.'<tr>
                        <td>'.$linha['nome_funcionario'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$linha['procedimento'].'</td>
                        <td>'.number_format($linha['valor'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>
                        <td>'.number_format($porcentagem).'</td>
                        <!--cell containing the sum-->
                        <!--<td>'.number_format($sum).'</td>-->
                        <td>'.fechaNormal($linha['start']).'</td>';     
}
$tabela = $tabela.'</table>';

$array = array(0 => $tabela,
               1 => $lista);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I enjoy some light ;)

Comment: Note that you can change: `$array = array(0 => $tabela,
               1 => $lista);` to just: `$array = array($tabela, $lista);`. Numerical keys are (of course) assigned automatically. Your approach would be used if you'd like to set the values to something else, but in this case it is redundant.

Comment: See similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464669/how-get-the-sum-for-every-distinct-value-in-another-column

Comment: "Among other columns there are "Column: Name" where the values are names and "Column: Value" where the values are numbers. " can't you make life easier for would be helpers by posting actual names or better still the tables

Comment: @e4c5 Looks like (Column)Name (Column)Value, eg:  e4c5:500,  e4c5:200 MAgicHat:100  MAgicHat:180, i need result e4c5:700 and MagicHat:280

Comment: Sorry that doesn't shed any light on this at all

Comment: @e4c5 http://i.stack.imgur.com/edwBe.png where nome_funcionário=Name and valor=Value